# Plotly ignores my custom colors in a 3d Scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, 3d, plotly, scatter

I'm rendering a 3D space that looks like half a sphere using a 3D Scatter plot in Plotly. I want to change the colour of each point according to the values in a Pandas DataFrame.

The rows of my DataFrame look like this:

```
{
   "x": 1,
   "y": -31,
   "z": -63,
   "M": -1,
   "E": -1,
   "F": -1,
   "CE": -1,
   "MA": -1,
   "R": -1
}
```

This way, in order to build my diagram I use:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(json_df, x="x", y="y", z="z", custom_data=["M", "E", "F", "CE", "MA", "R"])
fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "M: %{customdata[0]}",
        "E: %{customdata[1]}",
        "F: %{customdata[2]}",
        "CE: %{customdata[3]}",
        "MA: %{customdata[4]}",
        "R: %{customdata[5]}"
    ])
)
fig.show()
```

Which produces this image (if you also hover of each point, you get the info especified in `hovertemplate`):

[image]

Now I want to change the colour of each point according to those values M, E, F, etc., having a "default colour" for non-valid points (those where M, E, F, etc. is `-1`). Right now, I want to use a colour for non-valid points and a random-colour for valid ones.

Grey colour
[image]

```
grey_colour = 'rgb(84, 84, 84)'
def row_to_color(df_row):
    if df_row["M"] == -1:
        # non-valid colour
        return grey_colour 
    else:
        #randomly selected colour
        return 'rgb(' + str(0) + ', ' + str(np.random.randint(0,255)) + ', ' + str(np.random.randint(0,255)) + ')'

# Almost 2000-elements-long array, with a large part of it being that grey default color. 
custom_color = json_df.apply(row_to_color, axis=1)
fig = px.scatter_3d(json_df, x="x", y="y", z="z", custom_data=["M", "E", "F", "CE", "MA", "R"], color=custom_color)
```

However, Plotly ignores that non-valid colour (no matter what it is) and goes back to the default one, only respecting the colours that are different from the default one.

[image]

I've done some testing and if I use another condition (so there are far less "non-valid colour" items in the custom_color array), the plot seems to render correctly, but the colour is still incorrect. For instance:

```
def row_to_color(df_row):
    if df_row["x"] > 10: #less strict condition
        return 'rgb(84, 84, 84)' #grey
    else:
        return 'rgb(' + str(0) + ', ' + str(np.random.randint(0,255)) + ', ' + str(np.random.randint(0,255)) + ')'
...

fig = px.scatter_3d(...)
```

## Light orange ????

[image]

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3786#issuecomment-1162039382) to the main maintainer of Plotly, Nicolas Kruchten, (and [the official documentation of Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#directly-mapping-colors-to-data-values), that unfortunately I had misread), if you want to use a specific colour for every item that is going to be plotted in the final image, you just need to use the `color_discrete_map="identity"` argument when calling your plot function.

If you don't use it, Plotly tries to use the colours specified in the `color` array as colors to be assigned to **categories** of data. If you don't have categories, Plotly just goes nuts during the plotting.

By adding that parameter to the call, we tell Plotly to treat every item in the `color` array separately and set it as the colour for the corresponding item in the data provided.

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(json_df, x="x", y="y", z="z", 
    custom_data=["M", "E", "F", "CE", "MA", "R"], 
    color=custom_color,
    color_discrete_map="identity")
```

[image]